# Simulator background is dark / broken

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am following the Apple tutorial on Swift and for some reason my simulator background is black causing parts of the app to not show up correctly. This is what my simulator looks like

[image]

This is what it is supposed to look like (cropped because my screen won't fit)

[image]

I tried restarting simulator and Xcode but it won't go away. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you change your view background view to Default

[image]

It does looks the same in Interface Builder (Still White) but will be black in Simulator
try to change it back to White

Comment: I changed the background to white and still does not work.

Comment: its happen in other page or just this particular page?

Comment: This is a single page application and the only one I have created so far so I am not sure.